# Chmod permissions on files and directories

Tags: bash, permissions, file-permissions, chmod, user-permissions

I have a binary script along with a key file and required libs in a folder on my shell. There are 3 users on the shell currently whom I want to allow to run the binary script. Each user who runs it runs it as a separate instance/process. In order to start, the script is run by using an .sh file which specifies the location of the binary and its libs. For example, ./script.sh is the command.

I have the script currently in /home/script/user (will create also dir called /user2 for other user) where script is a new user I created for it. User runs the .sh from their homedir and then it automatically writes a config file in /home/script/user. I have been playing around with chmod because I don't want anyone to be allowed to steal the script or any of its contents inside the directory. To summarize, I only want users to be able to execute the binary and read the libs and key file as well as write their config to respective user directory in /home/script/. I don't want to allow them to delete, edit, copy, or download anything inside the /script directory. Currently only the binary can't be altered in anyway, but the key file and libs are able to be copied or downloaded. I couldn't figure out how to chmod the key and libs so that they can't be copied etc, only read to run binary successfully.

Please let me know how I can accomplish my permission goals and/or if there is another or easier way to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve most of what you want with `chmod` and groups. So to allow a bunch of users to run a script you'd create a group, add them to it. Create a group and add users to it like this:

```
groupadd <groupname>
usermod -a -G <groupname> <username>
```

Then to make a file only executable by a group you'd run

```
chgrp <groupname> <file>
chmod g+x <file>
```

Unfortunately because of the way that `chmod` works you cannot allow a file to be read but not copied. This is because chmod works with read, write and execute permissions and if you can read you can copy.

Comment: Basically it's the key file that I would like to protect mainly. I have the binary protected already, so now just the key file. Is there physically any possible way with still allowing read access?

Comment: Normally you'd have the key set to be only readable by the user(s) that need it. The problem isn't so much users that are allowed use of the key copying it. It's more of a problem when it's users that shouldn't be allowed use of the key copying it (or reading it at all). It's those users that you need to make sure don't have read access.